# in Python Is there ever a good time to use a global variable inside a class?

Tags: python, class, variables, global

Just a simple question of semantics. I am writing a simple function inside a class that goes like this:

```
class TheClass:

    def __init__():
         self.variable = 0


    def function(self):
        if self.variable == 9:
            #do these things
             self.variable = 0
        elif self.variable > 9:
            self.variable += 1
            #do these things until its time to
            #do the other stuff
```

Currently when I write code have lots of functions like this where i need a simple iterator
can count the number of times a function will run. However I feel like this is a very sloppy
way to code such a thing. And it makes for a heck of a time when i have lots of functions that need such a variable.

The only other way i can figure to code this is to add the global tag. like the following code. Is there a better way ???

```
def function:
    global variable
    if variable == 9:
        #do these things
         variable = 0
    elif variable > 9:
        #do this other stuff
        variable +=1
```

Comment: The global variable creates ambiguity between instance and static variables.

Comment: Try not to use global. If you do, try to use class instead.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your issue is with the first version, or how you think your second version is better.

Comment: I dont believe the second version is better. I am simply trying to find a way to encapsulate the iteration var so i do not end up with a pile of them in my init every time i write functions like this. I would love it if the function could be completely self contained and  still be able to hang on to the value of that var.

Comment: @Xzeion But you need the same number of variables, however you do it: one per separate loop. How is `global` possibly more "self contained"? The answer to the question "should I put this variable that I only need inside my class instances in the class or global namespace?" seems so obvious that I simply don't understand why you're asking it.

Comment: Perhaps a poor wording on my part. I dont like variables that float around at the top of my class when their only purpose is to iterate for the purpose of running code once every x runs. I want to make iterators inside a function. A though might be to use a for loop to call a function every x calls instead. I dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing more than a decade of python, and I *never* found a valid use case of using a global. The closest I've done was to build `singleton` at a module's level, somehow like the `log` instance.

Back to your code:

```
def function:
    global variable
    if variable == 9:
        #do these things
         variable = 0
    elif variable > 9:
        #do this other stuff
        variable +=1
```

I see no advantage of doing such a thing. Having variable being global makes it hard to know and analyze the life of the variable in your program, making it hard to debug. You can have other problems like shadowing in other functions, if they use the same name.

Python has been built to be OOP, and to help design OOP algorithms. Your following code may look a bit verbose:

```
class TheClass:
    def __init__():
         self.variable = 0

    def method(self):
        if self.variable == 9:
            #do these things
             self.variable = 0
        elif self.variable > 9:
            self.variable += 1
            #do these things until its time to
            #do the other stuff
```

but it helps a lot build correct algorithms. Because variable is not coming out of nowhere, but it's tied and encapsulated in the `TheClass` instance, so when you use it you do:

```
foo = TheClass()
foo.method()
```

If you find that to be too verbose for an algorithm as simple as yours, then you can simply make variable a parameter:

```
def function(variable):
    if variable == 9:
        #do these things
        variable = 0
    elif variable > 9:
        variable += 1
        #do these things until its time to
        #do the other stuff
    return variable
```

and then have:

```
modified_foo = function(original_foo)
```

and finally, another way would be to use closure on the function:

```
def other_function():
    variable = 0
    def function():
        if variable == 9:
            #do these things
            variable = 0
        elif variable > 9:
            variable += 1
            #do these things until its time to
            #do the other stuff

    # variable has not been modified
    function()
    # variable has been modified
```

which is not the best way to go, but has the good idea to limit the scope of variable to the `other_function()`'s scope.

Comment: Is there a way to declare the variable for that function inside the function without it losing its value between calls but also making it available to only that local function ?  Aka declaring a self.var inside the function???

Comment: it's called a static local variable in C functions, and no, it does not exists in python.